# How to implement large scrolling background image without tiles?

Tags: 2d, xna, sprites, side-scroller

I know that its just the background that scrolls and the player pretty much stays centered.  What I am wondering what technique is more correct when I am implementing a large side scrolling map (I am not using tiles like some other questions I have found).

using a very large map 16000 pixels map, and scrolling that. and create an image list, with maybe 4 4000 pixel maps?

also, lets say I want a box at a certain point in my map. Right now I am just counting the pixels that I am scrolling and once I get to pixel 2000 I insert the box, and scroll it with the background.  Does that seem correct? or is there a better way to do all of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SpriteBatch:

- Draw everything (`SpriteBatch.Draw`) in its "world space"
- Pass a translation matrix to `SpriteBatch.Begin` to translate your world space to the correct position (think of this like a camera).
- The maximum texture size in XNA is 2048x2048 on the Reach profile, 4096x4096 for HiDef ([details](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310004334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx)). If your background texture is bigger, you will have to split it up and draw it in parts.
- You may want to consider adding some [culling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game) ***if*** you hit performance issues.

You should do all your movement calculations and so on in that "world space". So that box would have a position of something like `new Vector2(2000, 0)`.

Your player would also have a `Vector2 position;` and probably also something like a `Vector2 velocity`. You would then `Draw` the player sprite at that position. And also use that position to create your camera matrix.

For *really* huge worlds, or for physics engines that require precision, you may need to mess about rebasing your world space to maintain precision ([details](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/about-floating-point-precision-and-why-do-we-still-use-it)). I imagine that this probably *doesn't* apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use an image list. (Is more memory friendly - although pay attention to the garbage collector)

Counting pixels can be good or bad. Depends on the complexity of your game. 
Pro: - it's pretty WYSIWYG.
     - it is simple to understand what's happening

Con: - Your smallest step-size is one pixel
     - maybe you want to be able to be more precise with your controls

My suggestion: If your game is reasonably simple use pixels. Otherwise calculate everything in a continuous space.

Comment: calculate everything in a continuous space seems like a good idea... if only I knew what that was.

Comment: The continuous space is where you do vector geometry ;-)

If you aren't very comfortable with linear algebra, stay with the pixels (or go to http://www.khanacademy.org/ and learn it)